# How do I order the languages in Gnome-language-selector?

Tags: language-support, support

I want to add English, Irish and Japanese in language support but despite it saying "Drag languages to arrange them in order of preference" it won't let me actually order them.
I want the order to be:
- English (UK)
- English (US)
- Gaeilge
- 日本語
- English
(It says English must always be last)

I've tried thouroughly to arrange them in this order but when I drag English (UK) / (US) above Irish or Japanese, it greys them out and puts them below English. This means I can only have the order Irish, Japanese and then the Englishes. I've tried editing /usr/local/locale but it doesn't actually affect the languages order used. Is this just a bug or it there something I'm missing. (I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS as a fresh install and I've purged Unity in place of GNOME (and don't say reinstall Unity because that's obviously not the solution))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, I have to confess: It's my fault. With that said, the reason for the behavior is that the desired order:

English (UK) - English (US) - Gaeilge - 日本語 - English

wouldn't make much sense. Please remember that the original language of Ubuntu is English (US), and hence it's always available. Fallback languages after English (US) should consequently never be used to display menus and messages.

This order ought to work:

English (UK) - English (US) - English

And that is probably what you want. You may want to click the <kbd>Help</kbd> button in the Language Support GUI to get a better understanding of what the language priority list is about.

HTH