# Ubuntu 18.04 Can't change preference order of languages in language menu

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

I want to add English and Japanese to the languages on my computer so I can use an input method editor to switch from one keyboard to the other. I want to keep English as the main system language for work but still be able to keep a Japanese keyboard handy, but all methods on the internet require me to reorder 'Japanese' between 'English (United Kingdom)' and 'English'. However, whenever I drag Japanese between these two languages, it either does not move to the space in between them or jumps up to the top. Attempting to displace it from the top will result in it being placed below English and thus not be considered. Is there any way I can edit this information from the terminal perhaps? This laptop is a bit of a potato since I need it to be expendable, so perhaps I might just be having problems with the incredibly computationally demanding tasks of dragging items in a dropdown menu? Please advise.

I've looked at [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988807/how-do-i-order-the-languages-in-gnome-language-selector) which says basically "oh you can't do it, it doesn't make any sense'. I've tried putting it between United States and normal english, between united states and UK english, but none of it works...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I confess: I'm guilty of that.

But I think that your whole question is a big misunderstanding. Initially you are talking about typing/inputting, but then you describe your attempts to modify the display language. Please note that input language and display language are two different things.

I'm assuming that what you really want is to make it easy to switch between English and Japanese as *input language*, and that you are fine with English as the *display language*. Is that correct?

As regards what you found on internet about reordering the stuff, you'd better explain better what you mean. There is reasonably more than one way to set it up. If you provide additional info, I'll edit this answer and add more specific guidance.